# Retrieving exact numbers from XML file

Tags: xml, variables, numbers, rounding

Im a php self-taught rookie, so please excuse my question if it's too dumb... I simply didn't know how to search for what I want in google as I am so bad with php I don't know what's happening...

Here's the situation:

- I have an XML file (http://www.pipsandtips.com/free/EURUSD.xml), and a php that takes data from it.
- what I'm trying to do is to color my table cells with a different color when their value (say r1) is within 0.0009 from any other (r2 to r6).
- to do this, I want to use a condition `IF ABS(r1-r2)>0.0009` -> make the cell yellow.
- but when I try to do the operation, it looks like only the number before the . is considered. If I try to add them up I don't get, say 2.2874 but 2. If I try to subtract one from another I don't get 0.0016 but 0. I can't setup my condition like this :(
- again: my knowledge of php and programming is zero, all I know is how to take stuff from online sources like stackoverflow and try to adjust numbers and variables to fit my needs... please help, I didn't even know what to look for in google because I can't explain the problem in a few words.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: contrary to popular belief, there IS such a thing as dumb questions, but yours is not one of them, so don't worry about it

Answer (score 0):

If your xml parsing has retained the full numerical string, you should be able to do the required operation. My PHP is rusty; I hope the following example is of help:

```
$num1 = floatval("1.22675");
$num2 = floatval("1.23675");

if ( abs($num2 - $num1) > 0.0009 )
    echo 'It Works';
else 
    echo 'Error';
```

Your issue is probably due to the loss of precision (the numbers after the ".") between floating point values and integer ones.